# Output in Textarea from User Input

Tags: javascript, html, output

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I just started learning JavaScript, and I came across a problem while coding a quick tool for a game that I play. I want users to be able to input a couple of things via an HTML Form and I want the JS Script to take that input and turn it into an SQL.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HabSQL - Online SQL Generator</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<header>Welcome to HabSQL v1.0! The Online Habbo SQL Generator!</header>
<p>HabSQL is strictly for use with Habbo Furniture SQLs and Data. Please enter all necessary information accordingly.</p>
<script src="scripts/habSQL.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:void(habSQL())">
<fieldset>
Furniture Name: <input id="furniName" type="text">
Furniture ID: <input id="furniID" type="number"><br>
SWF File Name: <input id="fileName" type="text"> (Exclude .SWF)<br>
Sprite ID: <input id="spriteID" type="number"> (We recommend that you use the same ID as Furniture ID).
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
Furniture Type: <input id="furniType" type="radio" value="s" name="furniType">Floor <input id="furniType" type="radio" value="i" name="furniType">Wall <input id="furniType" type="radio" value="e" name="furniType">Effect<br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
Furniture Width: <input id="furniWidth" type="number" class="dimensions"> Furniture Length: <input id="furniLength" type="number" class="dimensions"> Furniture Height: <input id="furniHeight" type="number" class="dimensions"><br>
Can you stack furniture on it? <input id="canStack" type="radio" value="1" name="canStack">Yes <input id="canStack" type="radio" value="0" name="canStack">No<br>
Can you sit on it? <input id="canSit" type="radio" value="1" name="canSit">Yes <input id="canSit" type="radio" value="0" name="canSit">No<br>
Can you walk on/through it? <input id="canWalk" type="radio" value="1" name="canWalk">Yes <input id="canWalk" type="radio" value="0" name="canWalk">No<br>
Can you recycle it? <input id="canRecycle" type="radio" value="1" name="canRecycle">Yes <input id="canRecycle" type="radio" value="0" name="canRecycle">No<br>
Can you trade it? <input id="canTrade" type="radio" value="1" name="canTrade">Yes <input id="canTrade" type="radio" value="0" name="canTrade">No<br>
Can you sell it on the Marketplace? <input id="canSell" type="radio" value="1" name="canSell">Yes <input id="canSell" type="radio" value="0" name="canSell">No<br>
Can you give it to someone as a gift? <input id="canGive" type="radio" value="1" name="canGive">Yes <input id="canGive" type="radio" value="0" name="canGive">No<br>
Can you stack it in the inventory? <input id="invStack" type="radio" value="1" name="invStack">Yes <input id="invStack" type="radio" value="0" name="invStack">No<br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
Interaction Type:<br>
<input id="intType" type="radio" value="default" name="intType">None<br>
<input id="intType" type="radio" value="bed" name="intType">Bed<br>
<input id="intType" type="radio" value="vendingmachine" name="intType">Vending Machine<br>
<input id="intType" type="radio" value="trophy" name="intType">Trophy<br>
<input id="intType" type="radio" value="gate" name="intType">Gate<br>
<input id="intType" type="radio" value="onewaygate" name="intType">One Way Gate<br>
<input id="intType" type="radio" value="dice" name="intType">Dice<br>
<input id="intType" type="radio" value="teleport" name="intType">Teleporter<br>
(More Interaction Types Coming in v2.0)<br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
How many interactions does the furniture have? (i.e. a dice has 6 sides and a closed side, therefore 7 interactions.)<br>
<input id="intCount" type="number"><br>
If your furniture gives out an item, what is the item's ID? 0, if none. (View external_flash_texts.txt or external_flash_texts.xml for ID #'s.)<br>
<input id="vendingID" type="number"><br>
</fieldset>
<input type="Submit" value="Generate!">
</form>
Furniture SQL:<br>
<textarea id="furniSQL" readonly="true" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS:

```js
// HabSQL - Online Habbo SQL Generator
// Developed by Thomas Yamakaitis - March 3, 2015
function habSQL() {
 var furniID = document.getElementById('furniID').value;
 var furniName = document.getElementById('furniName').value;
 var fileName = document.getElementById('fileName').value;
 var furniType = document.getElementById('furniType').value;
 var furniWidth = document.getElementById('furniWidth').value;
 var furniLength = document.getElementById('furniLength').value;
 var furniHeight = document.getElementById('furniHeight').value;
 var canStack = document.getElementById('canStack').value;
 var canSit = document.getElementById('canSit').value;
 var canWalk = document.getElementById('canWalk').value;
 var spriteID = document.getElementById('spriteID').value;
 var canRecycle = document.getElementById('canRecycle').value;
 var canTrade = document.getElementById('canTrade').value;
 var canSell = document.getElementById('canSell').value;
 var canGive = document.getElementById('canGive').value;
 var invStack = document.getElementById('invStack').value;
 var intType = document.getElementById('intType').value;
 var intCount = document.getElementById('intCount').value;
 var vendingID = document.getElementById('vendingID').value;
 var comma = ", ";
 var commaQuotes = "', '";
 var quoteComma = "', ";
 var commaQuote = ", '";

 document.getElementById('furniSQL').innerHTML = "INSERT INTO `furniture` (`id`, `public_name`, `item_name`, `type`, `width`, `length`, `stack_height`, `can_stack`, `can_sit`, `is_walkable`, `sprite_id`, `allow_recycle`, `allow_trade`, `allow_marketplace_sell`, `allow_gift`, `allow_inventory_stack`, `interaction_type`, `interaction_modes_count`, `vending_ids`, `is_arrow`, `foot_figure`, `height_adjustable`, `effectM`, `effectF`, `HeightOverride`) VALUES (" + furniId + commaQuote + furniName + commaQuotes + fileName + commaQuotes + furniType + quoteComma + furniWidth + comma + furniLength + comma + furniHeight + commaQuote + canStack + commaQuotes + canSit + commaQuotes + canWalk + quoteComma + spriteID + commaQuote + canRecycle + commaQuotes + canTrade + commaQuotes + canSell + commaQuotes + canGive + commaQuotes + invStack + commaQuotes + intType + quoteComma + intCount + comma + vendingID + ");";
}
```

I can't seem to pinpoint exactly what it is that I am doing wrong. If somebody could please assist me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Thanks to a few users here! The solution was a typo and I believe it was also value instead of innerHTML too.

Comment: Be very careful with SQL injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - sanitize and validate your inputs before running your SQL query...

Comment: The single quotes in your SQL string aren't quotes. They're the grave accent.

Comment: Thanks @ochi I'm not actually going to insert it, it's just a tool for people to get the actual SQL and insert it into their own database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple typo: `furniId` instead of `furniID` on the last line

JavaScript is case-sensitive so if you capitalize a variable name differently it's a completely different variable, and so it does not know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Textareas are modified by value, not innerHTML

so set it up to

```
document.getElementById('furniSQL').value = "INSERT INTO `furniture` (`id`, `public_name`, `item_name`, `type`, `width`, `length`, `stack_height`, `can_stack`, `can_sit`, `is_walkable`, `sprite_id`, `allow_recycle`, `allow_trade`, `allow_marketplace_sell`, `allow_gift`, `allow_inventory_stack`, `interaction_type`, `interaction_modes_count`, `vending_ids`, `is_arrow`, `foot_figure`, `height_adjustable`, `effectM`, `effectF`, `HeightOverride`) VALUES (" + furniId + commaQuote + furniName + commaQuotes + fileName + commaQuotes + furniType + quoteComma + furniWidth + comma + furniLength + comma + furniHeight + commaQuote + canStack + commaQuotes + canSit + commaQuotes + canWalk + quoteComma + spriteID + commaQuote + canRecycle + commaQuotes + canTrade + commaQuotes + canSell + commaQuotes + canGive + commaQuotes + invStack + commaQuotes + intType + quoteComma + intCount + comma + vendingID + ");";
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: You'll need to add single quotes on either side of values `+"'"+furniId+"'"+` You'll need to then escape single quotes that the user may have entered, with a separate function. Also you don't need single quotes around the field labels in your SQL statement. i.e. change `('id, 'public_name'...` to `(id, public_name...`

Comment: @TommyFilliater Thanks for the Reply, but it still did not work.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Thanks, I have single quotes in certain variables such as var comma = ", " and commaQuotes = ", '"
Is that alright? Or do you think I will have to do it manually?

Comment: `textarea` isn't inside the `</form>` tag

Comment: @ThomasYamakaitis http://jsfiddle.net/6aswa49z/ it should work, as many others have mentioned there's some issues with the SQL string, that might be it.

Answer (score 1):

You got a typo: `furniID` in your last element which is `document.getElementById('furniSQL').value=` is spelled as `furniId`